# App finished, Uploading to market?

Tags: android

I finished my android app now and i want to upload to the android market.. I have already bought the android license to upload i just want now to know what i need to do with my app.. I heard you need something signed and you need some key.. I can't remember all i heard but is there some complete guide for this or something i can read when i want to make my application into .apk and upload to market.. Im intrested in full guide so i might learn in the future how it works..

I did search the web before for this but they were so unclear guides how to do it.. Didn't help me much at all..

Answer (score 2):

The [Android publishing guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) explains this step by step. You must sign your app with your private key and generate the signed .apk file, as explained in the linked guide.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use Eclipse to sign your application. During the signing process you will be prompted to create a password.  Make sure you write this down as you will need this to sign updates to your app.  Once you've signed your APK, sign into the Android market (http://market.android.com/publish) and upload your binary.

Here's information on signing
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode

Answer (score 1):

Also, DO NOT lose the keystore file you need to create when signing your app. Without the original keystore file you will not be able to update your app to a newer version, because you won't be able to upload a newer version if it was not signed with the same certificate.